# LINQ ignore incorrect type being assigned to property

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have my own mapper (NOT AutoMapper) which maps models to each other. You give the model you'd like to map to, and with the Map method you push an object in. Beside of this I wrote the Extend method which functions as a override for the Map method to, for example, add properties which are not available in the object being mapped.

**Problem:**

The problem hereby is that my *`public Mapper<T> Extend(Func<T, T> func)`* method doesn't like the different types.

[image: LINQ compare error]

**Possible solutions:**

There are 2 solutions I'm thinking of:

1. Ignore the error and map the value within my *Extend* method. Which isn't possible as far as I know due to the expression being executed immediately.
2. Create a LINQ method which maps the value for me. Eg; `q => q.Ownership = obj.Ownerships.First().Map()`.

**Question:**
How can I resolve this error and achieve what I want?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, can you post your code?

Comment: Looks like you could define your `Extend` receiving an `Action<T>` instead of a `Func<T,T>`. That would allow you to pass `.Extend(q => q.Ownership = obj.Ownerships.First())`

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I still get the same error (cannot convert source type to target type).

Comment: That seems to be because `Ownership` in `DeviceModel` is of type `ViewModels.DeviceModel.OwnershipModel` while the object from `obj.Ownerships.First()` is of type `Portal.Models.Ownership`. You will need to convert from `Ownership` into `OwnershipModel` maybe using your mapper as in `q.Ownership = new Mapper<OwnershipModel>().Map(obj.Ownerships.First())`?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Isn't that a real quick 'n dirty hack? Besides the fact that it just works I'd prefer something more elegant and usable. 

(Sorry for me being a perfectionist. :))

Comment: That is usually done by the mapper. If the model you are mapping to has a property of type `FooModel` named `Foo` and the model you are mapping from has a property with the same name of type `Foo`, then the mapper will automatically map both using a mapper from Foo to FooModel. Because your mapper doesn't automatically map relationships, you need to manually map the relationship yourself...

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I'd love to automatically map this. Can you give me a direction to a resource describing how to implement this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at automapper and its source code. This is what [they describe](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings) as nested mappings, and you will be able to have a look at its source code.